# Regex: number or 2 numbers separated by ' - '

Tags: asp.net, regex

Can someone help me with a regular expression? I'd paste mine here but Stackoverflow doesn't seem to allow it so here's a screenshot:

[image]

It must match any number or any 2 numbers separated by a '-' and also only the first match.

Comment: It should be `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*-\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?$`

Comment: Actually, RegularExpressionAttribute only allows a full string match, you do not need the anchors, and you do not have to worry about matching the first match only.

Comment: Thanks this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*-\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MLUPnh/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits and an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `(?:\s*-\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\s*-\s*` - a hyphen enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits and an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.